# How does JSON.stringify make memoize function work?

Tags: javascript

```
   _  .memoize = function(func) {
  var hash = {};
    return function() {
      var arg = JSON.stringify(arguments);
      if (hash[arg] === undefined) {
        hash[arg] = func.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      return hash[arg];
    };
  };
```

Hello,

I am trying to implement the memoize underscore function. I have a question regarding to `JSON.stringify`.

In the `if statement` where it checks if the `arg` already exist or not in the `hash`. Why using `JSON.stringify` make it possible to check wether the input `arg` exist or not in the `hash`. I mean if we pass the `arguments` array without converting them using `JSON.stringify`, then we cannot check because we are passing an entire array. However, when using `JSON.stringify`, it makes it work. So how does `JSON.stringify` make it possible to check ?

Comment: Because it turns the arguments into a string, which can be used as a unique key…!?

Comment: Hmm...is this using the implicit arguments "array"?

Because that "arguments" array isn't actually an "array" at all (if I remember correctly). You had to do the Array.slice thing to convert it. 

So perhaps the stringify thing works around this and otherwise bulletproofs it somehow. Looking into it...

Comment: it seems to just be a (poor) way of checking if the member is a method and storing the result of invoking it if so

Answer (score 0):

It's because only strings can be used as keys in javascript objects. 
For example:

```
var key = {a:1};
var map = {};
map[key] = 1; 
// {'[object Object]': 1}
```

This will result in every arguments combination being `saved` in the same key.

Using `JSON.stringify` transform the arguments list in an unique string that can in turn be used as an unique object key.

```
var key = {a:1};
var map = {};
map[JSON.stringify(key)] = 1; 
// {'{"a":1}': 1}
```

This way, every time you call the function with the same arguments, `JSON.stringify` will return the same unique string and you can use that to check if you already have a cached result for that set of arguments, and if so, returning the cached value.

Comment: *"It's because only strings can be used as keys for javascript maps."* Careful with the terminology here. JavaScript has `Map`, which can take arbitrary values as keys. You are talking about *object*s.

Comment: i don't think that's why json.stringify is used here, most toString() methods would yield decent keys...

Comment: That's exactly why it is used, `({a: 1}).toString()` yelds '[object Object]` and the `arguments` variable is an object.  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 0):

The `hash` is a JavaScript object, which uses strings as keys. You cannot use an array (or array-like, in the case of `arguments`) there, so it needs to be converted to a string.

If no custom conversion is done, then the default serialisation would be `"[object Arguments]"` for *any* value of `arguments`. This is not unique and will not work with the intention of memoization.

```js
var hash = {};
var i = 0;

//a naive function that takes anything and puts it in a hash with a unique value
function populateUnique() {
  hash[arguments] = "Hello" + i;
  
  i++;
}

populateUnique("a");
populateUnique("b");
populateUnique("c", "d", "e");

console.log(hash); //only shows the last thing, as it it's always overridden.
```

This implementation chooses to employ `JSON.stringify` because it is quite straight forward - you could implement a custom serialisation function, but there is already one provided, so this is the simplest way to do it.

Should be noted that `JSON.stringify` is not bulletproof. It is easy to use and covers a lot of cases, but may blow up, for example, if you have circular references:

```js
var foo = {};

foo.bar = foo;

JSON.stringify(foo);
```

Since the `memoize` function does not control what will be passed in as arguments, it's possible that one of them, that is normally perfectly valid, will throw an error.

Another problem is if any of the arguments has its own `toJSON` method - this will be used for serialization, so you could end up in an interesting situation:

```js
var a = 42;

var b = {
  firstname: "Fred",
  lastname: "Bloggs",
  id: 42,
  toJSON: function() { return this.id }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(b));

console.log(a == JSON.stringify(b));
```

Comment: Might be valuable to point out the limitations of using `JSON.stringify`.